# How do I create system versioned tables using SSDT in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I'm trying to create Table with system versioning using Database Project.

1. Following schema gives error:

   > SQL70633: System-versioned temporal table must have history table name explicitly provided.

   ```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products]
    (
        [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        [ModifiedBy] NVARCHAR(127) NULL
    )
    WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON)
    GO
   ```
2. With explicit name:

   > SQL71501: Table: [dbo].[Products] has an unresolved reference to Table [history].[ProductsHistory].
   > SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near ].

   ```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products]
    (
        [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        [ModifiedBy] NVARCHAR(127) NULL
    )
    WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [history].ProductsHistory))
    GO
   ```

I've tried both, latest version of Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.5) and latest preview (16.8.0 Preview 3.2).

Comment: Have you tried this syntax in SSMS? Neither command contains the temporal columns or the PERIOD clause.

Comment: Ok, adding the columns changed the message `SQL71501: Table: [history].[ProductsHistory] has an unresolved reference to Schema [history].`. Adding CREATE SCHEMA [history] to a separate build script fixed this error. You want to write an answer?

Comment: You can also use the original query too, with an anonymous history table, as long as you include the columns

Comment: I created temporal tables directly in SSDT, imported them into a database project then deployed to another database with no issue

Comment: Yeah, I totally forgot about the temporal columns. You see, I've never used system versioning before and the error message was a bit misleading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax in both cases is invalid. Executing the first query in SSMS returns:

> Cannot set SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON when SYSTEM_TIME period is not defined.

The command needs a `PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME` clause specifying the columns used to specify the validity period of a record.

The [documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#creating-a-temporal-table-with-a-user-defined-history-table) show how to create a temporal table with a default, automatically named history table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products]
 (
     [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     [ModifiedBy] NVARCHAR(127) NULL,

     SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
     SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
     PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime)
 )
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON)
```

In this case, the `SysStartTime` and `SysEndTime` are used to specify the validity period of a record.

Similar syntax is needed to create a temporal table with a user-specified table name

```
create TABLE [dbo].[Products]
 (
     [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     [ModifiedBy] NVARCHAR(127) NULL,

     SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
     SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
     PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime)
 )
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.ProductHistory))
```

It's possible to create the history table on a different schema, eg `history`, as long as that schema exists, BUT it's probably not a good idea unless this solves some specific problem. The current and history table represent the same entity, depend on each other and have specific [security restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-security?view=sql-server-ver15) so storing them in separate schemas can make life harder.

To create the table in a separate schema, first create the schema :

```
CREATE SCHEMA history
```

Then use the schema in the table definition:

```
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = history.ProductHistory))
```